# BST: adding multiple values in a single node

Tags: c++, class, data-structures

Just started learning Binary Search Trees and my task requires, that I make a BST with structure something like this:

NODE: (contains) - String stringValue, int intValue ... k

1. *How can I implement BST* where I know for sure, that there will be atleast 1 String value, but with *unknown count* of int values?
   ( I'd love to understand how the ''NODE'' structure would look like (constructor as well) AND how the insertion/deletion would look look like... )

User can declare the count of int values. For instance: **John** can have 3 int values = **John 12 5 2** (one node).

Comment: `class Node { std::string stringValue; std::vector<int> intValues;};`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik by this structure my Node nr1. could look like "John 2 13 4" or Node nr1. "Peter 15 1"? Also, if this is correct, how would search work for this occassion? If I look for example1: "Peter" it would return me node nr1. as well if I'd look for "13" (also returns same node)?

Comment: A `Node`, as I defined it, can store a string and an arbitrary number of integers, if that's what you are asking. The search would work the way you implement it to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can create class with [variadic templates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_template):

```
template <typename T, typename... U>
class Node{
    public:
    Node(T nameStr, U... vInput){
        name = nameStr;
        list = {vInput...};
    }
    T name;
    std::array<int, sizeof...(U)> list;
};
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/k1sSH4).

Comment: Saurav - by this structure my Node nr1. could look like "John 2 13 4" or Node nr1. "Peter 15 1"? Also, if this is correct, how would search work for this occassion? If I look for example1: "Peter" it would return me node nr1. as well if I'd look for "13" (also returns same node)?